# jquery hover menu adding class with time

Tags: jquery

on some website I saw this effect: if I hover some menu background color doesn't change immediately but it changes in some specific time and it looks like it is animating, how can I get this effect?

Comment: jQuery doesn't inherently support color-animation, you will have to look into the UI.

Comment: Can you paste those site URL's. because may be they are used flash animation also.

Comment: Have you considered Googling for ["jQuery color animation"](http://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+color+animation)? Or if you don't want to use jQuery: ["Javascript color animation"](http://www.google.com/search?q=Javascript+color+animation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to look into is **CSS Transition Effects**. [Googled Results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css%20transition%20delay&aq=2&oq=css%20transition&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=css%20transition%20background%20color&oq=css%20transition%20backgrou&gs_l=serp.3.2.0l4.132349.134764.3.136310.10.3.1.6.7.1.137.348.0j3.3.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.bEwTeooMtEo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b42c98eb7706fa70&biw=1440&bih=815)

Take a look at this basic [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhBEg/) When you hoverover, the background color fades to red.

CSS

```
div{ 
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this can easily be done via css3 `transition` (without javascript) or doing an animation over a specific property on older browser

e.g. http://jsbin.com/ulayum/3/edit

```
a {
   color: 000;
   -webkit-transition: color 2s;
   -msie-transition: color 2s;
   -moz-transition: color 2s;
   -o-transition: color 2s;
   transition: color 2s;
}

a:hover {
   color: #ccc; 
}
```

Comment: interesting, I never knew you could do that with css

Comment: this is supported on every modern browser (except IE<9)

Answer (score 0):

This may be what your looking for

```
$("div").hover(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript's "setTimeout" function to add a delay to the effect..  Something like

pseudo code using jquery hover event:

```
.... .hover(function() {

      //on mouseover
      setTimeout(FunctionThatDoesSomethingCool(), 3000); //3000 = delay/milliseconds
},
function() {
       //mouseout
}
}); //end hover event
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is a plugin like thid one, so take a look at : [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).mouseover(function(){
 // change color   
}).delay('time');
```